# xslt xsl:copy not working as expected in masking an element value

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<Retails>               
    <Retail>                  
    <RetailTypeCode>CODE</RetailTypeCode>
    <Value>1111111111</Value>
    </Retail>
    <Retail>
    <RetailTypeCode>STATUS</RetailTypeCode>
    <Value>NotSet</Value>                
    </Retail>
    <Retail>                  
    <RetailTypeCode>USER</RetailTypeCode>
    <Value>David</Value>  
    </Retail>         
    <Retail>         
    <RetailTypeCode>PWD</RetailTypeCode>      
    <Value>aaaa</Value>       
    </Retail>          
</Retails>
```

I wanted to mask 1111111111, as, 1111XX1111.
with below xslt code, element  1111XX1111 is masking as expected.
However, subsequent elements NotSet , David , aaaa  are not appearing at all.

```
<xsl:template match="Value">
        <xsl:if test="string-length(.) &gt; 9">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(., 1,4),'XX',substring(., 7))">                  
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I want to retain all other element data, except masking one value as explained above.

Comment: Yo have a result for a case when the test returns true, but not when it returns false. Either use `xsl:choose` or match only the `Value`s that satisfy the condition (as shown in the answer below).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I really got your requirement, but this should do it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Value[string-length(.) &gt; 9]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(., 1,4),'XX',substring(., 7))"/>                  
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6q1SDkV/1

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. xsltfiddle has this by default and I forgot to remove it.